# How can I test that multiple booleans have identical values in c#?

Tags: c#, coding-style

Is there a shorter way of testing the following:

```
if (!((a == b) && (a == c) && (a == d) && (a == e) && (a == f)))
```

I ended up writing a method that lets me do this

```
if (!AllEqual(new[] { a, b, c, d, e, f }))
```

That feels nicer and is a lot more readable, but I'm wondering if there is something in the framework that does this already?

Comment: Your solution is the nicest I can think of off the top of my head.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well for one thing, you can use a parameter array to make it simpler:

```
public static bool AllEqual<T>(params T[] values)
...


if (AllEqual(a, b, c, d, e, f))
{
    ...
}
```

I don't think you'll find anything simpler than that, to be honest. I haven't seen this anywhere else, or in the framework. Well, I suppose there's *one* thing you could do in LINQ:

```
if (new { a, b, c, d, e, f }.Distinct().Count() == 1)
```

But that's pretty horrible :)

A slightly more efficient version of that is:

```
if (!(new { a, b, c, d, e, f }).Distinct().Skip(1).Any()))
```

... which will return false as soon as it finds the second distinct element. With only 6 elements I don't think it's worth worrying though :)

Comment: +1 And I also suggest OP not to use 6 bool variables, but one `bool[]` instead, which is also easier to query with `.Distinct`.

Comment: @Danny: I think it depends on the context - if the variables have very distinct meanings which just happen to make sense, then keeping them separate makes sense. If they're more similar - e.g. "is field 1 filled in, is field 2 filled in" etc - then an array would indeed be better.

Comment: Thanks for the param array idea. It does make the call simpler.

Answer (score 2):

**Only if a, b, c, d, e and f are booleans values:**

THe nicer way is to take a look in [Boolean logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_logic) and [logic gates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_gate) to [simplify](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/vol_4/chpt_7/5.html) your equation.

(The `==` is like an [XNOR gate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XNOR_gate) for boolean values)

An exemple for you:

```
(!((a == b) && (a == c) && (a == d) && (a == e) && (a == f)))
```

is the same than:

```
((a^b) || (a^c) || (a^d) || (a^e) || (a^f))
```

But I think it must be interesting do to a revue of the logic that comes to that

[EDIT] In relation with the [Hightechrider's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142004/how-can-i-test-that-multiple-booleans-have-identical-values-in-c/4142032#4142032), the proposition

```
((a^b) || (a^c) || (a^d) || (a^e) || (a^f))
```

is equivalent to:

```
((a != b) || (a != c) || (a != d) || (a != e) || (a != f))
```

But [Hightechrider's proposition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142004/how-can-i-test-that-multiple-booleans-have-identical-values-in-c/4142032#4142032) work perfectly even if a, b, c, d, e and f are not booleans.

Comment: I was aiming for readability. Though this is interesting I am not sure I will be able to read it tomorrow.

Comment: I can understand you if you're not aware on boolean logic: it took me a while to get used with it. however I think it's a very important think to learn, even if in this case Jon Skeet,'s answer seems to be the best solution, compared to your question ^^

Comment: Obviously, I agree that completely factored/simplified form of a complex boolean expression is really hard to understand without a quick comment with its developed form

Answer (score 1):

You could distribute the ! into the expression:

```
if ((a != b) || (a != c) || (a != d) || (a != e) || (a != f)))
```

You could also use `Any` or ! `All` rather than adding a new method.

```
if (new[]{b, c, d, e, f}.Any(x => x != a)) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this to check that they are all true:

```
if (a && b && c && d && e && f) {
    ...
}
```

and this to check that they are all false:

```
if (!(a || b || c || d || e || f)) {
    ...
}
```

and you could combine both to check that they are all equal:

```
if ((a && b && c && d && e && f) || !(a || b || c || d || e || f))
    ...
}
```

But quite frankly, this is not better than your original solution :-)

Based on the above, here is a possible implementation of `AllEqual`:

```
public static bool AllEqual(bool[] values)
{
    bool andTerm = true;
    bool orTerm = false;
    foreach (bool v in values)
    {
        andResult &= v;
        orResult |= v;
    }
    return andTerm || !orTerm;
}
```

Comment: False: in `(a && b && c && d && e && f)` if a, b, c, d, e, and f are `true`, your solution return `true`, whereas `(!((a == b) && (a == c) && (a == d) && (a == e) && (a == f)))` return `false`, and `!(a || b || c || d || e || f)` return `true` if a, b, c, d, e, and f are `false` whereas `(!((a == b) && (a == c) && (a == d) && (a == e) && (a == f)))` return `false`... And the third alway return `true` when a, b, c, d, e and f are equal, unlike `(!((a == b) && (a == c) && (a == d) && (a == e) && (a == f)))` who always return `false` in this case...

Comment: @G. Qyy: The title of the question says: "How can I test that multiple booleans have **identical values** in c#?". The code snippets in the question actually use this to test that they values are **not** equal, but an `AllEqual` function is what the OP is explicitly asking for. My answer explains: 1) How to test for all true, 2) How to test for all false, 3) How to test for all equal. My code does what I say it does.

Comment: You're right in this point: I understand he want to reproduce the behavior of it's first test, and I care a few of title because they rarely expose the complete complexity of the question... Of course, your code is right compared at what you say it does. my apologies ^^

Answer (score 1):

Use [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray%28VS.71%29.aspx):

> Manages a compact array of bit values,
>   which are represented as Booleans,
>   where true indicates that the bit is
>   on (1) and false indicates the bit is
>   off (0).

```
// Your collection of bits
bool a = false, b = false, c = false;
// get them into an array
bool[] d = new bool[] { a, b, c };
// intialize BitArray with that array
System.Collections.BitArray e = new System.Collections.BitArray(d);
// use OfType<>, Any<>, All<>
if (Convert.ToBoolean(e.OfType<bool>().Any<bool>(condition => condition.Equals(true)) && e.OfType<bool>().Any<bool>(condition => condition.Equals(false)))) Console.WriteLine("some one is TRUE!.");
```

A sample Console Application code for demonstration:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool a = false, b = false, c = false;
            bool[] d = new bool[] { a, b, c };
            System.Collections.BitArray e = new System.Collections.BitArray(d);
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(e.OfType<bool>().Any<bool>(condition => condition.Equals(true)) && e.OfType<bool>().Any<bool>(condition => condition.Equals(false)))) Console.WriteLine("some one is TRUE!.");
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(e.OfType<bool>().Any<bool>(condition => condition.Equals(true)) && e.OfType<bool>().Any<bool>(condition => condition.Equals(false)))) Console.WriteLine("some one is FALSE!.");
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(e.OfType<bool>().All<bool>(condition => condition.Equals(true)))) Console.WriteLine("All of them are TRUE!.");
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(e.OfType<bool>().All<bool>(condition => condition.Equals(false)))) Console.WriteLine("All of them are false!.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

*MSDN Documentation on* [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

How about..

```
List<bool> arr = new List<bool>{ a, b, c, d, f };
bool allEqual = arr.TrueForAll(x => { return x; }) || arr.TrueForAll(x => { return !x; });
```

Looks pretty elegant to me. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's such a good idea to introduce a dependency to a framework only for that.

Comment: He said *the* framework - as in the main .NET framework, I'd imagine.

Answer (score 0):

That's not something people usually want to know. You could easily check that they were all true by just and-ing them together, or that they were all false by and-ing their nots together. It's also popular in C++ to cast bools to ints and add them up - in your case you'd be looking for a total of 6 or 0. But I think both of those would obscure whatever business reason you have for knowing that 6 flags are either all true or all false.